# Connecting client to JBoss cluster

Tags: jboss, client-server, jboss5.x, cluster-computing

I am new to JBoss. Basically I have managed to cluster 2 nodes with:

Node 1: run.bat -c all -g DefaultPartition –u 230.0.0.4 -b 10.67.51.28 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1

Node 2: run.bat -c all -g DefaultPartition –u 230.0.0.4 -b 10.67.50.21 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=2

I know that if i cofigure a Apache load balancing(Mod_JK) to sit infront of the cluster, the client simply just punch in the IP of the Apache, and Apache will redirect the traffic to the nodes.

But I do not want to have a Apache infront of the cluster. So how do my client access the cluster?? Do i need to configure something in JBoss, or isit a MUST to have a load balancer for the client to access the cluster??

MANY thanks in advance....

Comment: It sounds like you should really read through the [JBoss Clustering Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/5/html/index.html). And, what's wrong with using `mod_jk`?

Comment: Hi matt, thanks for the advise, and is it possible for you to direct me where exactly in the guide i should be forcusing? Basically my boss just wants me to prove that JBoss is able to perform failover. I have done it with a load balancer. But she doesnt wants it. So i am not to sure how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Apache is not strictly needed to perform failover.  But you will need some infrastructure level to redirect the requests to the other server when the first one is down.

To achieve failover with JBoss; the default is to use several JBoss nodes (in cluster mode to replicate session data) and in-front a network http level infrastructure that route the request to the correct JBoss instance.  Several routing strategies can be performed e.g. load balancing the session base on available nodes (the default used by most Java EE systems) or one node taking all load and ip change done automatically if the environment detect one node is down.

The first one is provided by the mod_jk and is probably simpler at a correct price.

To perform high availability you will need a complete redondent infrastructure, router, switch etc. and several reverse proxy (the Apache node) below a hardware HA load balancer.

If you only have 2 JBoss node, how the request going to the down node will be rerouted to the fail over node?

If it helps, re-brand the Apache node to "Fail over request router"...